# Swift SKScene shows as blank in Objective-C project

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, sprite-kit

I have an Objective-C based project in Xcode. I'm trying to add a SpriteKit scene as a smaller view in a view controller. The SpriteKit files are in swift though. I've added Floor1.sks and linked it with Floor1.swift.

Now I'm trying to load it into my Objective-C ViewController.m file. In my storyboard I made the view to the class SKView, and I think I properly made a bridging-header file. My code to insert it at the moment is:

```
GKScene *scene = [GKScene sceneWithFileNamed:@"Floor1"];
Floor1 *sceneNode = (Floor1 *)scene.rootNode;
sceneNode.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFit;

SKView *skView = (SKView *)_skView;

[skView presentScene:sceneNode];

skView.showsFPS = YES;
skView.showsNodeCount = YES;
```

The view loads when I run the app successfully, but it's just an empty view with a light grey background with the node count which is 0, and the FPS. What am I doing wrong, how come it won't load my proper view?

Comment: Put a breakpoint  and see if scene is being initialized. By the way, what is the Floor1 (what is scene.rootNode)?

Comment: @Whirlwind Floor1 is the name of my scene. There's Floor1.sks and Floor1.swift. In the sks I have its Custom Class set to the swift file. And for the code to load my view (the only code in my question^^), it's just copied/pasted into my project. I can't seem to get it to work though

Comment: Why do you load GKScene from the Floor1.sks then? Your code is a bit confusing. For example, it seems that your scene has a property rootNode that is scene as well. You cant have a scene in a scene. I mean theoretically you can, but scene that is added as a child to another scene will act as ordinary node.

Comment: @Whirlwind I tried to load the sks because I thought that's what the view is. In the inspector of sks on the sidebar I set the Custom Class to its swift counterpart. They should be linked now right? What should I do to load my view instead? I'm new at this :/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Forgive my english, i use google translator.
I decided to look at it as written files when I create a new cross-platform game. Namely cross-platform. It does not have much other scene initialization. And it all worked for me. Used to work only on iOS 10, and now iOS 9.
Screenshots I attached to them

[GameViewController.m](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5YAJ.png)

```
    #import "GameViewController.h"
#import "GameScene.h"

@implementation GameViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    GameScene *scene = [GameScene newGameScene];

    // Present the scene
    SKView *skView = (SKView *)self.view;
    [skView presentScene:scene];

    skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = YES;
    skView.showsFPS = YES;
    skView.showsNodeCount = YES;
}
```

[GameScene.m][2]

```
#import "GameScene.h"

@implementation GameScene {
    SKShapeNode *_spinnyNode;
    SKLabelNode *_label;
}

+ (GameScene *)newGameScene {
    // Load 'GameScene.sks' as an SKScene.
    GameScene *scene = (GameScene *)[SKScene nodeWithFileNamed:@"GameScene"];
    if (!scene) {
        NSLog(@"Failed to load GameScene.sks");
        abort();
    }

    // Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window
    scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;

    return scene;
}
```

[GameScene.h][3]

```
#import <SpriteKit/SpriteKit.h>

@interface GameScene : SKScene

+ (GameScene *)newGameScene;

@end
```