# How do I load a .sks linked with .swift class into a UIViewController in my Objective-C project

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, sprite-kit

I have an Objective-C based project in Xcode. I'm trying to add a SpriteKit scene as a smaller view in a view controller. The SpriteKit files are in swift though. I've added Floor1.sks and linked it with Floor1.swift.

Now I'm trying to load it into my Objective-C ViewController.m file. In my storyboard I made the view to the class SKView, and I think I properly made a bridging-header file. My code to insert it at the moment is:

```
GKScene *scene = [GKScene sceneWithFileNamed:@"Floor1"];
Floor1 *sceneNode = (Floor1 *)scene.rootNode;
sceneNode.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFit;

SKView *skView = (SKView *)_skView;

[skView presentScene:sceneNode];

skView.showsFPS = YES;
skView.showsNodeCount = YES;

//skView loads blank grey screen
```

The view loads when I run the app successfully, but it's just an empty view with a light grey background with the node count which is 0, and the FPS. What am I doing wrong, how come it won't load my proper view?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift SKScene shows as blank in Objective-C project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41946374/swift-skscene-shows-as-blank-in-objective-c-project)